# I have a problem with the task of reversing words and removing parentheses

Tags: python

Task

> Write a program that will decode the secret message by reversing text
> between square brackets. The message may contain nested brackets (that
> is, brackets within brackets, such as `One[owT[Three[ruoF]]]`). In
> this case, innermost brackets take precedence, similar to parentheses
> in mathematical expressions, e.g. you could decode the aforementioned
> example like this:
>
> 1. One[owT[Three[ruoF]]]
> 2. One[owT[ThreeFour]]
> 3. One[owTruoFeerhT]
> 4. OneThreeFourTwo
>
> In order to make your own task slightly easier and less tricky, you
> have already replaced all whitespaces in the original text with
> underscores (“_”) while copying it from the paper version.
>
> Input description
>
> The first and only line of the standard input
> consists of a non-empty string of up to 2 · 106 characters which may
> be letters, digits, basic punctuation (“,.?!’-;:”), underscores (“_”)
> and square brackets (“[]”). You can safely assume that all square
> brackets are paired correctly, i.e. every opening bracket has exactly
> one closing bracket matching it and vice versa.
>
> Output description
>
> The standard output should contain one line – the
> decoded secret message without any square brackets.
>
> Example
>
> For sample input:
>
> ```
> A[W_[y,[]]oh]o[dlr][!]
> ```
>
> the correct output is:
>
> ```
> Ahoy,_World!
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> This example contains empty brackets. Of course, an empty string, when
> reversed, remains empty, so we can simply ignore them. Then, as
> previously, we can decode this example in stages, first reversing the
> innermost brackets to obtain `A[W_,yoh]o[dlr][!]`. Afterwards, there
> are no longer any nested brackets, so the remainder of the task is
> trivial.

Below is my program that doesn't quite work

```
word = input("print something: ")
word_reverse = word[::-1]
while("[" in word and "]" in word):
    open_brackets_index = word.index("[")
    close_brackets_index = word_reverse.index("]")*(-1)-1
    # print(word)
    # print(open_brackets_index)
    # print(close_brackets_index)
    reverse_word_into_quotes = word[open_brackets_index+1:close_brackets_index:][::-1]
    word = word[:close_brackets_index]
    word = word[:open_brackets_index]
    word = word+reverse_word_into_quotes
    word = word.replace("[","]").replace("]","[")
    print(word)

print(word)
```

Unfortunately my code only works with one pair of parentheses and I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hint: You'll probably have to take advantage of the stack data structure.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your code in words?

Comment: You may also be able to use recursion for this.

Comment: Everyone see [How do I ask and (*especially*) answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Does the assignment allow use of regular expressions i.e. "import re"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the re module can be used, this code does the job:

```
import re

text = 'A[W_[y,[]]oh]o[dlr][!]'

#  This scary regular expresion does all the work:
#  It says find a sequence that starts with [ and ends with ] and
#  contains anything BUT [ and ]
pattern = re.compile('\[([^\[\]]*)\]')

while True:
    m = re.search(pattern, text)
    if m:
        #  Here a single pattern like [String], if any, is replaced with gnirtS
        text = re.sub(pattern, m[1][::-1], text, count=1)
    else:
        break
print(text)
```

Which prints this line:

```
Ahoy,_World!
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize the my previous answer has been accepted but, for completeness, I'm submitting a second solution that does NOT use the re module:

```
text = 'A[W_[y,[]]oh]o[dlr][!]'

def find_pattern(text):
    #  Find [...] and return the locations of [ (start) ] (end)
    #  and the in-between str (content) 
    content = ''
    for i,c in enumerate(text):
        if c == '[':
            content = ''
            start = i
        elif c == ']':
            end = i
            return start, end, content
        else:
            content += c
    return None, None, None

while True:
    start, end, content = find_pattern(text)
    if start is None:
        break
    #  Replace the content between [] with its reverse
    text = "".join((text[:start], content[::-1], text[end+1:]))
print(text)
```